# .Net Core OpenIDConect using third party provider

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-view-controller, openid-connect

I am on .Net core 3.1 , using OpenIDConnect to authenticate, Here is my startup.cs

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
           .AddCookie()
           .AddOpenIdConnect("test",o =>
           {
               o.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
               o.SignOutScheme = "Cookies";
               o.ClientId = "test";
               o.ClientSecret = "gs";
               o.Authority = "https://test";
               o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
             o.MetadataAddress = "https://test/.well-known/openid-configuration";
              o.SaveTokens = true;
               o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
               o.Scope.Add("openid");
               o.Scope.Add("profile");
           });


            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }
```

Here is my Home Controller and action Login with [Authorize] attribute

```
 [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
      
        return View();
    }
```

Login button is on Home folder Index.cshtml

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Login" target="_self" role="menuitem" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnLogin" aria-label="Log in to your account">LogIn</a>
```

When I click on Login button, this is the error:

> No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:34343/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FLogin

Why is it trying to go to Account/Login ?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

by

```
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

Comment: no-authenticationscheme-was-specified-and-there-was-no-defaultchallengescheme, this is the error

Comment: Unable to get OpenID to work with third part identity server. Any tips ?

Comment: so add this : options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

Comment: This is the error message "InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions)."

Comment: this is how my startup.cs looks like  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
               
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
              
            })

Comment: Got it to work by removing authorize attribute and challenging from within the action

Comment: public IActionResult Login([FromRoute] string provider, [FromQuery] string returnUrl)
        {
            returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? "/" : returnUrl;
            var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = returnUrl };
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, authenticationProperties);
        }